# What can we do with UCWA API (Lync)? and What can we not do with UCWA API?

Tags: ucwa

Please explain what are features available in UCWA API (Lync)?  I'm interested in the following:

- Screen Sharing?
- Video Chatting?
- Voice Chatting?
- Send a file?
- I want to access UCWA API in android code, is it possible?

Comment: You appear to have 3 separate questions asking similar information and might be best to combine to avoid repeating information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good wealth of information surrounding UCWA is available at http://ucwa.lync.com paying specific attention to the Documentation menu.  A good rundown of features can be found at [Core-Features](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/core-features) which do not currently (CU3+) include screen sharing, video, voice, data collaboration (sending a file).

It is possible to place a audio call using a feature named Call-Via-Work which requires the user provide a callback number that Lync will use to connect you with the remote party, but it is not exactly the same as an audio call between two parties.

> I want to access UCWA API in android code, is it possible?

There are sample libraries available ([UCWA Helper Libraries](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313244)) in JavaScript, but it is quite possible to use the libraries to construct code to run on an Android platform (Java, etc).

Comment: The problem is that the Helper libraries are deeply integrated into the HTML running the Javascript. I did however run into this yesterday, which might help offer a cleaner approach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn551186%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As per the [About](https://ucwa.lync.com/about/about-ucwa) link of UCWA, API helps you to do the following things,

-Anonymous Web Chat.
-Support audio conferencing
-Light up IM & Presence in your Line-Of-Business app, including Windows 8, iPad, and others
-Inline Instant Messaging into your application (Contextual Communications)
-Search for Skype and/or business contacts
-Better together with UCMA Customer Care family of apps

Also you can refer this site [UCWA Capabilities](http://mohamedasakr.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/inside-ucwa/)